# Remove a user id from array of ids

Tags: javascript

I would like to remove the user id from the array(there are two of them)

```js
const user = {
  "_id": "5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d"
}

const allowners = [
  "5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d",
  "5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b",
  "5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8",
  "5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d"
];

const vendors = []
allowners.forEach((allowner) => {
  if (allowner != user._id) {
    vendors.push(allowners)
  }
})
console.log(vendors, user._id)
```

Comment: you can use filter instead of forEach

Comment: Can you format the example array a bit better? Like ```users = [["id1.1", "id2.1"],["id1.2", "id2.2"]]```?

Comment: See the linked question's answers, a simple `filter` does the job: `const vendors = allowners.filter(owner => owner !== user._id);`.

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Comment: If you want vendors to contain only unique IDs, you might want to consider `Set`s. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: TYPO: `vendors.push(allowner)` not `allowners`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Code works just fine if he pushes what he passes - it is not a dupe but a typo

Comment: [ 5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d,
  5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b,
  5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8,
  5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d ]
[ 5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d,
  5d6caee9bb6f2921f45caf1b,
  5d6dfcd6e3b11807944348b8,
  5d6caefdbb6f2921f45caf1d ]
i am getting such a result @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @vithushaji that is not a valid JS array. You need quotes. See the snippet I made for   you. Please write such snippets in the future. It was much easier to see your mistake in a running example

Comment: Also you want `let vendors = []` since it is not a constant unless you filter or map the allowners into it

Comment: i concatinated two arrays and then it lost double quotes
const allowners = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], owners)
@mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan - Yes it is. `vendors` will always refer to the array. The fact the array is mutable has nothing to do with the declaration of `vendors`.

Comment: `vendors.push(allowners)` is the typo - not pushing owner: `allowners.forEach(owner => {
  if (owner != user._id) {
    vendors.push(owner)
  }
})`